# Edit existing airflow DAGs made by someone else without original files

Tags: airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs

I've taken over some DAGs left by some consultants, all I have is admin access to view the webserver info: "https://airflow.companyname.com",

And when I go into Configurations, it shows something like this:
The home folder for airflow, default is ~/airflow
airflow_home = /usr/local/airflow

And I do not have access to any of those local files.

Is there a way I can connect to this airflow and edit the dags?

Comment: You can't edit from UI but if you have access to the container or machine on which airflow running then you can find all dag files inside $AIRFLOW_HOME/dags (probably /usr/local/airflow/dags in your case) folder and can edit

Comment: @PankajSingh thanks for the tip. I did find the container, it's running on AWS ECS,
I pulled the image, made some changes and built a new one and changed all the services to the new image (force new deployment), but I do not see any changes to the WebUI, would you know why would that happen?